# SQL querying over multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I don't have much experience in SQL so I think this is not a dumb question.

I have 2 tables like this.

[image]

A .. G are the members of a hierarchy.

Now my requirement is as follows.

> I need to filter out the members which
> has status = 0 from Members table.
>
> But, If the selected set contains
> children which has a parent with
> status = 0, Ignore the child and
> select only the parent.

As an example, in the above case the set with 0 status = {B,C,D,E,F,G}
But C,D,E,F has status 0 parents.
So my result should be {B,G}

**Can I do this just by using SQL and related technologies?** (i.e In database layer. I don't want to query into the data structures and then iterate. Can I write a single query for this?)

I will add some more examples if the question is confusing?

Comment: Interesting question. Now, do you care about the whole relationship tree, or only about direct ancestor? E.g. if the grandparent (or great-grandparent, etc.) has status = 0, do you want the child shown? In your example, assuming everyone except B = 1, and B = 0; do you want to show F, even though it has an ancestor with status 0, several levels above?

Comment: @ Piskvor : If D = 1 in above example it is still sufficient to get {B,G}. I don't want to get {B,E,G} as a result. (If a parent has state 0, then it should be in the set but not any of its children.)

Comment: Not an answer, but combine this with @gandjustas's answer and you'll get what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select m.ID from Members m
left join Relations r on r.Child = m.Id
left join Members p on r.Parent = p.Id
where m1.Status = 0 and p.Status <> 0
```

But i think there will be a recursive query.

Comment: This would result in B only. Still G is a member with status 0 and I need to get that listed because it is not a child of anyone. What is the best way to do this? Just "UNION"ing?

Comment: select m.ID from Members m
left join Relationships r on r.Child = m.Id
left join Members p on r.Parent = p.Id
where m.Status = 0 and p.Status <> 0
union
select ID from Members Where Status=0 AND NOT ID IN (SELECT Child from Relationships union SELECT Parent from relationships)

Comment: This answer is just plain incorrect. Left outer join is one way to express a `not exists`; however, the outer join criteria would have to include `p.Status = 0` and the `where` clause would have to restrict the result to `p.Status is null`.

Comment: Yes, there should be m.Status = 0 and (p.Status <> 0 or p.Status is null) in Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what you need using just SQL.

Since parent and child must both have status 0 to be considered, let me rephrase your query:

Return all members with status 0 that have no parent(s) with status 0.

There are several different ways to write a "not exists" query like the above. One example is:

```
select *
from Members
where ID not in (
    select Child
    from Relationships r join Members m on r.Parent = m.ID
)
```

Things would get a little more complicated if you were returning parents regardless of status, but you are not.